# Regex: Capturing a hashtag when it is the first character of a tweet

Tags: twitter, hashtag

/[\s\W]#(\w+)/g

This is a very simple that will still correctly capture most desired tweeter hashtag cases, **EXCEPT** for the special case where the hashtag is actually the first word with no leading characters:

[image]

http://regexr.com/3h2rr

If we make the first character set *lazy* it will correctly capture the first hashtag, but also incorrectly not reject hashtags with leading alphanumeric characters

[image]

http://regexr.com/3h2ru

A programatic workaround can simply be: "always adding a space to the begining of the tweet string", thus bypassing the limitation of this simple expression, **but now I'm really curious to see how to do this the right way.**

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
/[\s\W]*#(\w+)/g
```

This should allow for no preceding character to be needed, might not be the most beautiful way to do this though.

Comment: :( that may be, but also fails to not capture the asdasd#correctly_not_captured tag